# How to dynamically use Python's type hinting to indicate a return value to be the same as a parameter's type

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

I'm using Python to read JSON from disk, and I'm trying to make sure my type hints are correct downstream. For example, something like this:

```py
from typing import List

def verify_contains_ints(items: List[object]) -> List[int]:
    for item in items:
        if not isinstance(item, int):
            raise TypeError("List contents must be all ints")
    return items
```

The problem I'm running into is that I don't want to write separate functions for int, bool, str, etc. Is there a way to dynamically specify the type I want to verify? What I'd like *like* to write is something like this:

```py
from typing import List

def verify_contains_type(items: List[object], inner_type = object) -> List[inner_type]:
    for item in items:
        if not isinstance(item, inner_type):
            raise TypeError(f"List contents must be all {inner_type}s")
    return items
```

Is there a way to do this in the current state of type hinting?

Note: this is a simplified version of what I'm actually trying to do. The default inner_type might seem silly here, but it is important for my use case.

Comment: This isn't an answer yet, but nicer dynamic type checks of parameterized generics should be possible some time after python 3.9: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use `typing.cast` here, which is slightly ugly. Note, it has no run-time effects, it simply returns what was passed into it, although it does incur a function-call overhead. But it tells the type-checker "this is now of this type". You should use a `TypeVar` to make it generic, then simply pass the type like you were trying to do, and annotate it with `Type`

```
from typing import List, TypeVar, Type, cast

T = TypeVar('T')
def verify_contains_type(items: List[object], inner_type: Type[T]) -> List[T]:
    for item in items:
        if not isinstance(item, inner_type):
            raise TypeError("List contents must be all ints")
    return cast(List[T], items)


mylist: List[object] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

safe_mylist: List[int] = verify_contains_type(mylist, int)
print(safe_mylist[0] + safe_mylist[1])
```

mypy is happy now:

```
(py38) juan$ mypy --version
mypy 0.750
(py38) juan$ mypy test_typing.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: This looks mostly good, except that when I try to default inner_type to object for when people won't know/care about the type, mypy complains. Any idea around that? This is perfect, other than that one issue.

Comment: if you know how to make the inner_type default to object, I will make this the accepted answer  :)

Comment: @micseydel, see my answer about the default type of inner_type. If these two together answer your question please accept juanpa.arrivillaga's answer, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you are ok with constructing a new list:

```py
from typing import List, Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def verify_contains(items: List[object], inner_type: Type[T]) -> List[T]:
    # Mypy currently needs this hint to infer what 'clean_items' is
    # supposed to contain. Other type checkers may not.
    clean_items: List[T] = []
    for item in items:
        if not isinstance(item, inner_type):
            raise TypeError("List contents must be all ints")
        clean_items.append(item)
    return clean_items
```

If you're not familiar with what TypeVars are, they're a way to let you write generic code. See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html for more details.

Type lets you specify that you want a class object, rather than an instance of a class. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects for more details.

---

The reason why we need to create a new list is because if we don't, you could introduce a bug to your code due to mutation. For example:

```py
original: List[object] = [3, 2, 1]
all_ints = verify_contains(original, int)

# Legal, since strs are a kind of object
original.append("boom")

# ...but if verify_contains doesn't return a copy, this will
# print out [3, 2, 1, "boom"]!
print(all_ints)
```

If you're ok with ignoring this potential bug, use a cast as suggested by some of the other answers.

---

Yet another alternative approach might be to just use a library like [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) instead of writing this validation logic yourself.

This is personally the approach I would take: I can focus on just writing high-level schemas using PEP 484 types and let the library handle validation for me.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [the answer of juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60160399), but with supporting a default `inner_type` of `object`. The best way I can find is using a combination of `typing.Union` and `typing.overload`. I must confess this is quite verbose, but as least no functional changes to the code are required.

#### Solution

```
from typing import List, Type, TypeVar, Union, cast, overload, 

T = TypeVar('T')


@overload
def verify_contains_type(items: List[object], inner_type: Type[T]) -> List[T]:
    ...

@overload
def verify_contains_type(
    items: List[object], inner_type: Type[object] = object
) -> List[object]:
    ...

def verify_contains_type(
    items: List[object], inner_type: Union[Type[T], Type[object]] = object
) -> Union[List[T], List[object]]:
    for item in items:
        if not isinstance(item, inner_type):
            raise TypeError(f"List contents must be all {inner_type!r}")
    return cast(List[T], items)
```

After this:

```
mylist: List[object] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Revealed type is 'builtins.list[builtins.float*]'
my_floats = verify_contains_type(mylist, float)


# Revealed type is 'builtins.list[builtins.object]'
my_whatevers = verify_contains_type(mylist)
```

#### Explanation

When analyzing the usage of the function, the type checker will only look at the `@overload` function definitions, checking them in the specified order until a match is found. The type annotations in the actual function are *not* taken into account.

When analyzing the code inside the body of the function itself, the type check will only use the type annotation of the actual function and ignore the  `@overload` definitions.

Additional information on `@overload`:

- [Mypy documentation on function overloading](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#function-overloading)
- [Official Python documentation of typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)

Comment: I haven't spent the time to fully understand this (especially the overload part), but doesn't `Union[List[T], List[object]]` defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: @micseydel, no the `Union` will not be used by the type checker, but I understand the confusion. I've added some extra explanation and can recommend the Mypy docs for some more in-depth on function overloading in general.